# Copy Method not Working when Range is set to a Variable in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range

I want to copy a range into another range in different sheets. I wanted to assign variable names to the ranges so I can do multiple things with the same ranges without rewriting them again.

This code is working

```
 Worksheets(yeniListSheet).Range("A" & y & ":" & "H" & y).Copy (Worksheets(eskiListSheet).Range("K" & eskiLisRowNum))
```

But this code is not working

```
Dim fromR, toR As Range
Set toR = Worksheets(eskiListSheet).Range("K" & eskiLisRowNum)
Set fromR = Worksheets(yeniListSheet).Range("A" & y & ":" & "H" & y)
fromR.Copy (toR)
```

The error is "copy method of range class failed"

What is the problem in the 2nd code? How am I supposed to write it like the 2nd code?

Comment: `fromR.Copy toR` (no parentheses).

Comment: Yeap, it was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Declare like this: `Dim fromR As Range, toR As Range`. Otherwise only the last `toR` gets declared as a `Range`, the `fromR` is a `Variant`.
- Remove the parenthesis from `(toR)`. It causes an error, because the parenthesis force taking the parameter `ByVal`. And a `Range` object is passed by reference.

Then try this, hardcoding the variables, to make sure that you have correct values for `eskiLisRowNum` and `y`:

```
Public Sub TesMe()
    Dim fromR As Range, toR As Range
    Set toR = Worksheets(1).Range("K" & 2)
    Set fromR = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & 1 & ":" & "H" & 2)
    fromR.Copy toR
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand why you wanted me to change my declarations and to try hardcoding but removing the parenthesis worked thanks.

Comment: @WVrock - Welcome. The declarations are changed, because otherwise the `fromR` is initially a `Variant`. The hardcoding was to make sure that `y` and `eskilisrownum` have valid values.

Comment: ah. I always assumed that they are both declared as range when declaring like that

Comment: @WVrock - nope. But now you know :)